# Lodash Pull not working

Tags: javascript, lodash

If I run the following code, the length does not change:

```
console.log(files.length);
_.pull(files, [files[0], files[1]]);
console.log(files.length);
```

where `files` is an Array object. Shouldn't `pull` definitely find matches to remove given that I'm constructing its second arguments with values directly from the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should pass in an array of values you want to 'pull'. The documentation suggests they should be separate arguments like so:

```
_.pull(files, files[0], files[1]);
```

https://lodash.com/docs#pull

Comment: When I use `_.pull(files, files[0], files[1]);`, executing in node, I get a RangeError originating from `pull` itself.

Comment: Maybe you should log out the values of files[0] and files[1] to make sure they are sensible. It's also possible that you have an old version of lodash and the method signature has changed, but I would be surprised at that.

Comment: I did some testing and for some reason trying to change the length property or doing anything that would cause the engine to implicitly change the length, such as calling files.splice, will throw a RangeError

Answer (score 1):

> for some reason trying to change the length property or doing anything that would cause the engine to implicitly change the length, such as calling files.splice, will throw a RangeError

Why not create a new array, using [without()](https://lodash.com/docs#without) to remove the unwanted files?

```
var newFiles = _.without(files, files[0], files[1]);
```